# phpdoc / phpcodesniffer checkstyle file

Tags: php, jenkins, phpdoc

I'm using Jenkins to build my php projects.
I use some config found in the internet which is based on phpcodesniffer to display code styling violations. I'm very happy with the results.

Some time ago I was using also phpdoc which was informing me about missing comments doc blocks in files.

Now I wanted to use it's feature to prepare better docs. Unfortunately the information of missing docblocks is saved to file checkstyle.xml - the same used by codesniffer.

The question is - how can I change codesniffer PSR-2 configuration to allow informing me about missing blocks or alternatively - how can I combine in Jenkins output of those two processes.

Maybe there is any other way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Jenkins plugin that processes that checkstyle file will allow you to put in a wildcard pattern, rather than insisting on just a literal filename.  So, if phpdoc produces checkstyle-phpdoc.xml, and phpcs produces checkstyle-phpcs.xml, then set the Jenkins plugin to look for checkstyle-*.xml.  I'm expecting that it will merge all matching files and process it as one batch.

Comment: OMG, too easy to spot. Actually I was able to specify two filenames after comma as they are in separate dirs. Thanks!